# How to init an empty np array and add one-dimensional ones to it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to create an empty array into which I can add other arrays and get a matrix:

```python
arr = np.array([])
arr = np.append(arr, [1, 2])
arr = np.append(arr, [3, 4])
```

As a result, I get a one-dimensional array:

```python
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```

Expected result:

```python
array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
```

I tried to init an array as multidimensional `arr = np.array([[]])`, and not append but concatenate arrays `arr = np.concatenate((arr, [1, 2]), axis=0)`. Both options did not work, the result was again a one-dimensional array.

So, what's the best way to fix this and get a two-dimensional array as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the lists in a list, and do one array construction at the end:

```
In [687]: alist = []
     ...: alist.append([1,2])
     ...: alist.append([3,4])
     ...: arr = np.array(alist)    
In [688]: alist
Out[688]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]    
In [689]: arr
Out[689]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Repeated `np.append` and `np.concatenate` is inefficient, and hard to get right.

Why are you surprised that you got a 1d array.  Did you skip the `np.append` docs?  Without `axis` that's what is does.  With `axis` it just does `np.concatenate`.  And as you found `concatenate` is picky about dimensions.  You can join a (0,2) with a (1,2) on axis 0, but not a (1,0) with a (2,).

Imitating list methods with arrays doesn't work - unless you the read documentation carefully.

"empty array" is an ambiguous phrase.  `np.empty((1000,20,30))` makes a very large array of "arbitrary" values.  `np.array([])` makes a float dtype array with shape (0,).  That has 0 elements, but so does an array with shape (10,0,1000).  Lists are inherently 1d; arrays have both shape and dtype.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved my problem. Special thanks for additional explanations!

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with an array with the right dimensions and append using the same dimensions. You also need to note whether you are appending rows or columns, otherwise `np.append` will flatten the result into a 1d array. Since you are starting with an empty array, you'll need to use a function that lets you specify the shape on creation. And then wrap the new rows in an outer list to make them 2d.

```
>>> arr=np.zeros((0,2), dtype=int)
>>> arr = np.append(arr, [[1,2]], axis=0)
>>> arr = np.append(arr, [[3,4]], axis=0)
>>> arr
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

As a side note, each append copies the array, which gets more and more expensive as the array grows. If you are using append to create a large array row by row, you should consider alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays have a fixed size. Therefor appending a value to an array is not possible.

There is a number of ways to achieve your goal. The simplest of them is probably just using the `np.array` method:

```py
np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
```

You can also create a new array of the desired size containing all zeros using `np.zeros()` and copy the values into this new array afterwards like this:
1

```py
arr = np.zeros((2, 2))
arr[0, :] = [1, 2]
arr[1, :] = [3, 4]
```

Or you can stack the row arrays using `np.stack`:

```py
np.stack([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

### Edit

If you do not know the required size of the array at creation time you can create a two dimensional array and use `np.append` to create a copy of the initial array with the new value appended to it:

```py
arr = np.zeros((0, 2)) # Create an empty array with a row length of 2
arr = np.append(arr, [[1, 2]], axis=0)
arr = np.append(arr, [[3, 4]], axis=0)
```

The double square brackets are crucial because this makes the array two dimensional.

Comment: But numpy _does_ have an "append" method. Sure, it copies, but its still append as far as the numpy programmers are concerned. With your solution, you need to know the final size of the array in advance. That's not necessarily a bad thing as repeated appends get slower and slower as the array grows and the copy is more expensive.  Which way to go is an open design decision.